# Removing duplicate code with multiple APIs

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, api, api-design

I have multiple APIs doing the same thing but the code is copied for each API. The names of fields and formats of certain fields like dates are different between the various APIs, but everything is ultimately the same. I would like to remove duplication of logic and change these APIs to call the service layer.

I have started removing duplication of some code. Each API has a class which the JSON maps to. This allows for various names and formats in each API. In the controller for each API I convert that class to a unified class with the appropriate formats and names. I then pass this to a unified service layer. The service layer then returns a unified object and that gets mapped to the API specific response object. This seems to be working well.

The problem I am running into is handling errors. Instead of validating on each individual class that the JSON was mapped to I now validate the single class. When there is an error the expected error output is supposed to have something like:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "error": "DOB cannot be in the future",
            "field": "dob"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is if one of the APIs has the field dateOfBirth instead of dob then the field in the error object is not correct.

I see two solutions for this:

1. I could have a process that remap each the error fields back to what each of the individual APIs needs.
2. I can do the validation on each of the individual APIs instead of the shared single class.

I don't particularly like any of these solutions. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Why not have your validator extract the name of the field, from the field it is validating, or be told the name of the field to validate? That way you could assemble your validator from lists of basic validators. The DOB date restriction simple becomes `DateMustBeHistoric("dob")` or `DateMustBeHistoric("dateOfBirth")` alternataly `DateMustBeHistoric(typeof(X).member("dob"))` (however  the language supports reflection).

Comment: @Kain0_0 I might be misunderstanding what you are saying, but I am doing this for the shared class. My shared class for example has dob, but my API has dateOfBirth. I am grabbing the name of the field from the validator, but since I am validating on the shared class it grabs dob. I do have shared validation like a DOBValidator, but I am applying it to the shared class. Are you suggesting validating on each individual API? I was concerned that I would forget a field and let invalid data go through.

Comment: So you are constructing a domain object capable of domain behaviour, from an unvalidated data source, and then validating it? That is a serious security issue. Yes the response from each API should be individually validated, because they are not identical, and deserialisation is a form of `eval()` that must be guarded from abuse. Yes you should also be validating the domain object, just not after the fact. The domain object knows that DOB should be less than today, if that is not the case when it is constructed, or when its mutators are used, then it should throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, that would mean double validation. The first round of validation is proving that the API is behaving correctly. The second round of validation is proving that your program is behaving correctly. If speed is key, that is the only time you should write a direct API->Object mapping function. It will be a source of defects later so make sure the speed benefit is worth it.